# Devise's "timeout_in" not working for dev only mode (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm simply just trying to disable the feature that requires me to login after inactivity in my development environment. To configure this, I have the following set:

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb

Devise.setup do |config|
   ...
   config.timeout_in = 30.minutes if Rails.env.production?
   ...
end
```

However, every time I'm inactive for 30 minutes, I look up and realize I have to login again.

Any suggestions on how to turn this off? Quite surprised that this isn't working since this seems to do the trick for most of other non-devise features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

config.timeout_in has a default value, so if you don't assign it, it will default to 30 minutes. Try this:

```
config.timeout_in = 1440.minutes if Rails.env.development?
```

This will give you 24h. I don't know if there is any timeout limit, but you can try 1.year :)

Another option could be to activate the remember me.